# Typescript considers the json file content as empty object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a config.json file:

```
{
  "attribute": "value"
}
```

When I try importing it:

```
import data from './config.json'

class Service1 {
    private config: Record<string, unknown> | undefined
    initConfig(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
        this.config = data
        return this.config
    }

    getAttribute(){
        const {attribute} = this.initConfig(data)
        return attribute
    }
}
```

I got the tslint error for the line `const {attribute} = this.initConfig(data)`:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Why typescript considers the data as an empty object?

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: Are you using [the `--resolveJsonModule` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule)?  If so, could you possibly reproduce your problem in a web IDE project like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?  Without seeing this in front of me it's hard to know what else to say.

Comment: @jcalz I tried to make the example with a similair config file on this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-bduqfq?file=src%2Findex.ts
But there is an issue with the editor to import the config.json file.

Comment: I don't know what to say, sorry.  If you manage to demonstrate your issue, I'd be happy to look at it.